# Check if json object is undefined

Tags: jquery, json, amazon-web-services

I am using the amazon product api, my requests return xml in which encode to json.

Some items in my feed to not have a price, therefore I get the following error

```
TypeError: this.ItemAttributes.ListPrice is undefined
```

However I can retrieve a sale price. So I want to basically see if

this.ItemAttributes.ListPrice is undefined  if so then look for this...

this.Offers.OfferListing.Price.FormattedPrice

How can I do this in jQuery?

I tried this..

```
if (this.ItemAttributes.ListPrice != null){
var price = this.ItemAttributes.ListPrice;
}else{
var price = this.Offers.OfferListing.Price.FormattedPrice
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nearly. You want to be checking for `undefined`, not `null`.

One way to do it may be :

```
var price;
if (this.ItemAttributes.ListPrice !== undefined) {
    price = this.ItemAttributes.ListPrice;
}
else {
    price = this.Offers.OfferListing.Price.FormattedPrice;
}
```

If you want to cover for all falsy values (null, undefined, zero...) you may just turn the first line into :

```
if (this.ItemAttributes.ListPrice) {
   ...
```

[More here about falsy values](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

You may write it more succintly using || or ? operators, but be sure to keep it readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're checking multiple values, it may be easier to write a function to check the value, return it if it's not undefined or null, or return false if it is.

```
var checkObj = function(obj) {
    if(obj != null || obj != undefined) {
        return obj;
    } else {
        return "Unavailable";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If at least one of those prices is set, this should work.

```
var price = this.ItemAttributes.ListPrice ? this.ItemAttributes.ListPrice : this.Offers.OfferListing.Price.FormattedPrice;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.ItemAttributes.ListPrice != null || this.ItemAttributes.ListPrice != undefined){
var price = this.ItemAttributes.ListPrice;
}else{
var price = this.Offers.OfferListing.Price.FormattedPrice
}
```